# Regex for parsing sub string of URL

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

```
function init() {

            $.get("/example/abc/include.txt", function(script) {
               code goes here
            });
            $.get("<http>://abc.com/example/abc/dontinclude.txt", function (script) {
                code goes here
                }
            });
        }
```

I am trying to parse  the above string to list all the URL's which starts from /example and ends with file name like abc.txt.

So the desired list should be:
 `/example/abc/include.txt`

I tried with the following regex :

```
(\/)[^\s\/]?(example\/)(\w+\/)*(\w+.\w{3,4})
```

But it list two URLs as below:

```
/example/abc/include.txt
/example/abc/dontinclude.txt
```

I changed the above regex to :

```
\"(\/)[^\s\/]?(example\/)(\w+\/)*(\w+.\w{3,4})\"
```

This returns the required URL but I want exclude the double quotes from the result.

Any Idea how to remove the double quotes using the regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you read the matched results. 
You could use another group surrounding everything but the double quotes:

```
\"((\/)[^\s\/]?(example\/)(\w+\/)*(\w+\.\w{3,4}))\"
```

or you could use a positive lookbehind, that ensures that the character before is a double quote:

```
(?<=\")(\/)[^\s\/]?(example\/)(\w+\/)*(\w+\.\w{3,4})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The positive look-forward (?<=\") is not c# regex flavor. I tried the same in c# flavor `(?=\")(\/)[^\s\/]?(example\/)(\w+\/)*(\w+\.\w{3,4})`. But it didn't work.

Comment: The positive lookbehind is C# regex flavor. (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx). Have you escaped the double quote correct? `@"(?<=\"")(\/)[^\s\/]?(example\/)(\w+\/)*(\w+\.\w{3,4})"`

Comment: Yes @Yosh you are right. I tested it in wrong tool. Its working fine now. Thanks.